# KOMAScript on Microsoft

Tags: lyx, koma-script

I recently recommended lyx to a fellow writer. He downloaded it onto his MS box, but the download evidently didn't include KOMAScript.

Questions:

Does the CTAN KOMAScript package run on MS? 
If not, where can he find a version that does?

I'm a Linux user so the MS world is land of mystery to me.

Many thanks,

LRP

Comment: What did he download? As you probably know, LyX is a front-end: it needs a TeX system installed to work. Both LyX itself and TeX systems (TeX Live, MiKTeX) are available on Windows, so there should be no issue.

Comment: Yes it does. Does your fellow writer use MikTeX or TeXLive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a guess, but I think he did only a basic installation of MiKTeX on Windows (which does not include KOMA-Script).  The standard methode of MiKTeX is to download only the basic version and to install on the fly missing packages (runs only if you have a permanent internet conection).

You can use the package manager of MiKTeX (click `start` -- `all programs` -- `MiKTeX 2.9` -- `Maintanance` -- `Packagemanager` -- `KOMA-Script` (search for it in the list, press `k` to jump to letter k) to install missing packages to MiKTeX.

I personally prefere to have a complete installed MiKTeX.